# Is IntentService appropriate for FileObserver

Tags: android, android-intentservice, fileobserver

I need to set a FileObserver on a directory. The observation period is linked to a long running activity, long running because it has a ViewPager with a lot of pages. Instead of placing the FileObserver inside the activity, I was thinking of putting it inside a service. Now I am wondering would I use IntentService or should I roll out my own implementation of Service? My real concern is that I do not want the service to stop until I explicitly call stopService(intent). But I understand that IntentService stops itself. So how would an IntentService stopping itself affect the life of my FileObserver? Very importantly, I want to start observing the moment my activity starts to when my activity is destroyed.

So I suppose an important question is: Is it necessary at all to place my FileObserver in a Service, since I plan to startWatching in onCreate and stopWatching in onDestroy of my Activity?

**update**

I am using the FileObserver to remove the files from the directory being observed to put them in another directory. Actually before putting in the new directory I resize by about a factor of 20. So all that needs to happing in the `onEvent` method of the FileObserver, which is why I am thinking a service with an independent thread is important. And I need to observe for about 3 hours at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it necessary at all to place my FileObserver in a Service, since I plan to startWatching in onCreate and stopWatching in onDestroy of my Activity?

No.

That being said...

> would I use IntentService

No.

> or should I roll out my own implementation of Service?

Yes.

> My real concern is that I do not want the service to stop until I explicitly call stopService(intent).

This is why you would not use `IntentService`, as it stops itself when `onHandleIntent()` returns.

> So how would an IntentService stopping itself affect the life of my FileObserver?

That depends on what you are doing with the `FileObserver` with respect to the `IntentService` lifecycle. Either:

- You are removing the `FileObserver` at the end of `onHandleIntent()`, in which case you won't be observing files for very long
- You are removing the `FileObserver` in `onDestroy()`, in which case you won't be observing files for very long, as the service will be destroyed shortly after `onHandleIntent()` returns
- You are not removing the `FileObserver` at all, which is a bug in your app

> Very importantly, I want to start observing the moment my activity starts to when my activity is destroyed.

Then have the `FileObserver` in the activity.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Each time I refer to onDestroy, I am referring to my Activity -- not to the service. Sorry for confusion.