# Long running operation inside onEvent of FileObserver

Tags: android, android-service, android-intentservice, fileobserver

I have an activity that contains an Instance of FileObserver. I start watching in onCreate and stop watching in onDestroy of the activity. So what happens if onEvent is doing some operation and the activity is destroyed (user presses back button)? Does my onEvent continue to finish what it was doing? Basically I am wondering whether onEvent should start a service or handle its business itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the Application is stopped the code in your onEvent will continue to run.

[FileObserver.onEvent documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html#onEvent%28int,%20java.lang.String%29)

> This method is invoked on a special FileObserver thread. It runs independently of any threads, so take care to use appropriate synchronization! Consider using [`post(Runnable)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#post(java.lang.Runnable)) to shift event handling work to the main thread to avoid concurrency problems.

So the only think you need to be concerned with is what exactly you are doing in `onEvent`. For instance if you are updating UI or interacting with the `Activity` / `Fragment` in your `onEvent` method then this could cause a crash if the `Activity` goes away.

With that in mind a service will certainly increase the odds that the application does not terminate while you are performing your work.

[Service documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

> The Android system will force-stop a service only when memory is low and it must recover system resources for the activity that has user focus. If the service is bound to an activity that has user focus, then it's less likely to be killed, and if the service is declared to [run in the foreground](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground) (discussed later), then it will almost never be killed. Otherwise, if the service was started and is long-running, then the system will lower its position in the list of background tasks over time and the service will become highly susceptible to killing—if your service is started, then you must design it to gracefully handle restarts by the system. If the system kills your service, it restarts it as soon as resources become available again...

So the bottom line is that a service is more likely to keep your application alive. Event more likely if you call [`startForeground`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification)) but in this case you need to be willing to show a notification to the user.

Comment: I read that but wasn't sure of the implication. So is there any benefit from starting an IntentService to do the work that was to be done in here? I think Services have higher priority than mere threads. So how does this FileObserver compare? Or would I have to do something extra to my IntentService to give it greater protection than this onEvent method?

Comment: Yes definite benefit. See my update and @CommonsWare's answer. While a service is running your application is less likely to be terminated by the OS to free up resources for other applications.

Comment: @NouvelTravay Added more details regarding the service / application lifecycle.

Answer (score 2):

> Does my onEvent continue to finish what it was doing?

At least briefly, yes. `FileObserver` is not tied to a specific component's lifecycle, like that of an `Activity`.

However, once your app is no longer in the foreground, your process can be terminated at any point, to free up system RAM for other apps. Android is not going to pay any attention to your `FileObserver` and its `onEvent()` processing when this occurs, by default.

If you expect the work to happen quickly — say, under a second — you should be able to keep it where it is.

If, however, the sort of work that you are doing is more substantial, I would consider having a service do the work. Per our [prior discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34663840/is-intentservice-appropriate-for-fileobserver), while the `FileObserver` should not be in an `IntentService`, the work triggered by the `FileObserver` could be. `onEvent()` would call `startService()` to tell the service to go do the work. Services are a signal to the OS that you are actively doing work on behalf of the user, and so your process is more likely to hang around for a bit longer.